Type guard for verifying that each item of a tuple is defined
This is closely related to Type guard for verifying that each item of an array is defined except the accepted answer there does not work for tuples.
The accepted answer's type guard is similar to this:
function isDefined<T> (value: NonNullable<T> | undefined | null): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value !== null && value !== undefined
}

function isEachItemDefined<T> (value: ReadonlyArray<NonNullable<T> | undefined | null>): value is ReadonlyArray<NonNullable<T>> {
  return value.every(isDefined)
}

But I am in a situation like this:
type Test = { value: number };
const array: readonly [Test | null, Test | null] = [null, null];

if (isEachItemDefined(array)) {
  const [val1, val2] = array;
}

The type of val1 and val2 is Herp | null. I want to make a type guard which would remove null from val1 and val2. Ideally, the type guard should work with arbitrary arrays - mutable, readonly, tuples and unordered. Any idea how to go about it?

What's a "const array"? Do you mean a tuple?  If so, then I would write it with a mapped type as in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes it's a tuple, eg. ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const (aka const array in my head). Seems like the playground link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Please copy/paste it to an answer so I can accept it.

If the array is a tuple type you can use a mapped array/tuple type to apply NonNullable to each element type, like this:
function isEachItemDefined<T extends readonly any[]>(
    arr: T
): arr is { [I in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[I]> } {
    return arr.every(v => v != null)
}

If T is a plain array type like Array<X>, then the guarded type will just be Array<NonNullable<X>>.  But if T is a tuple like [X, Y, Z], then the guarded type will apply NonNullable to each element like [NonNullable<X>, NonNullable<Y>, NonNullable<Z>].  It will also work for readonly arrays and readonly tuples.
Let's test it out:
type Test = { value: number };
const array: readonly [Test | null, Test | null] = [null, null]; 
if (isEachItemDefined(array)) {
    array; // const array: readonly [Test, Test]
    const [val1, val2] = array;
    val1.value;
    val2.value; 
}

Looks good.
Playground link to code
